# SQLAlchemy order_by many to many relationship through association proxy

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, many-to-many

I have a many to many relationship setup in a Flask app in SQLAlchemy using a Association Object. I then have have assocation proxies setup between the the classes, to give more direct access rather than going via the association object.

Here is an abbreviated example of the setup:

```
class Person(Model):
    __tablename__ = 'persons'
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    last_name = Column(Text, nullable=False)
    groups = association_proxy('group_memberships', 'group')
    # Other stuff

class Group(Model):
    __tablename__ = 'groups'
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    name = Column(Text, nullable=False)
    members = association_proxy('group_memberships', 'person')
    # Other stuff

class GroupMembership(Model):
    __tablename__ = 'group_memberships'
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    person_id = Column(Integer, ForeignKey('persons.id'), nullable=False)
    group_id = Column(Integer, ForeignKey('groups.id'), nullable=False)
    person = relationship('Person', uselist=False, backref=backref('group_memberships', cascade='all, delete-orphan'))
    group = relationship('Group', uselist=False, backref=backref('group_memberships', cascade='all, delete-orphan'))    
    # Other stuff
```

What I cannot for the life of me figure out is how to get the members returned by `group.members` to be sorted by their `last_name`?

Comment: You don't need the `uselist=False` arguments on the relationships as they're defined on the referencing side, or in other words a `GroupMembership` entity can reference only one `Person` and `Group`. You'd use it in one to one relationships.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

In order to sort `group.members` you have to have the Persons available for sorting while loading the GroupMembership association objects. This can be achieved with a join.

In your current configuration accessing `group.members` first loads the GroupMembership objects, filling `group.group_memberships` relationship, and then fires a SELECT for each Person as the association proxy accesses the `GroupMembership.person` relationship attributes.

Instead you want to load both the GroupMemberships and Persons in the same query, sorted by `Person.last_name`:

```
class GroupMembership(Model):
    __tablename__ = 'group_memberships'
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    person_id = Column(Integer, ForeignKey('persons.id'), nullable=False)
    group_id = Column(Integer, ForeignKey('groups.id'), nullable=False)
    person = relationship('Person',
                          backref=backref('group_memberships',
                                          cascade='all, delete-orphan'),
                          lazy='joined', innerjoin=True,
                          order_by='Person.last_name')
    group = relationship('Group', backref=backref('group_memberships',
                                                  cascade='all, delete-orphan'))
    # Other stuff
```

You need to define the `order_by='Person.last_name'` on the scalar relationship attribute `GroupMembership.person` instead of the backref `Group.group_memberships`, which could seem like the logical thing to do. On the other hand [`order_by`](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/orm/relationship_api.html#sqlalchemy.orm.relationship.params.order_by) "indicates the ordering that should be applied when loading these items", so it makes sense when using [joined loading](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/orm/loading_relationships.html#joined-eager-loading). Since you'll be joining a many-to-one reference and the foreign key is not nullable, you can use an inner join.

With the given definition in place:

```
In [5]: g = Group(name='The Group')

In [6]: session.add_all([GroupMembership(person=Person(last_name=str(i)), group=g)
   ...:                  for i in range(30, 20, -1)])

In [7]: session.commit()

In [8]: g.members
2017-06-29 09:17:37,652 INFO sqlalchemy.engine.base.Engine BEGIN (implicit)
2017-06-29 09:17:37,653 INFO sqlalchemy.engine.base.Engine SELECT groups.id AS groups_id, groups.name AS groups_name 
FROM groups 
WHERE groups.id = ?
2017-06-29 09:17:37,653 INFO sqlalchemy.engine.base.Engine (1,)
2017-06-29 09:17:37,655 INFO sqlalchemy.engine.base.Engine SELECT group_memberships.id AS group_memberships_id, group_memberships.person_id AS group_memberships_person_id, group_memberships.group_id AS group_memberships_group_id, persons_1.id AS persons_1_id, persons_1.last_name AS persons_1_last_name 
FROM group_memberships JOIN persons AS persons_1 ON persons_1.id = group_memberships.person_id 
WHERE ? = group_memberships.group_id ORDER BY persons_1.last_name
2017-06-29 09:17:37,655 INFO sqlalchemy.engine.base.Engine (1,)
Out[8]: [<__main__.Person object at 0x7f8f014bdac8>, <__main__.Person object at 0x7f8f014bdba8>, <__main__.Person object at 0x7f8f014bdc88>, <__main__.Person object at 0x7f8f01ddc390>, <__main__.Person object at 0x7f8f01ddc048>, <__main__.Person object at 0x7f8f014bdd30>, <__main__.Person object at 0x7f8f014bde10>, <__main__.Person object at 0x7f8f014bdef0>, <__main__.Person object at 0x7f8f014bdfd0>, <__main__.Person object at 0x7f8f0143b0f0>]

In [9]: [p.last_name for p in _]
Out[9]: ['21', '22', '23', '24', '25', '26', '27', '28', '29', '30']
```

A downside of this solution is that the `person` relationship is always loaded eagerly and the ORDER BY applied when querying for GroupMemberships:

```
In [11]: session.query(GroupMembership).all()
2017-06-29 12:33:28,578 INFO sqlalchemy.engine.base.Engine BEGIN (implicit)
2017-06-29 12:33:28,578 INFO sqlalchemy.engine.base.Engine SELECT group_memberships.id AS group_memberships_id, group_memberships.person_id AS group_memberships_person_id, group_memberships.group_id AS group_memberships_group_id, persons_1.id AS persons_1_id, persons_1.last_name AS persons_1_last_name 
FROM group_memberships JOIN persons AS persons_1 ON persons_1.id = group_memberships.person_id ORDER BY persons_1.last_name
2017-06-29 12:33:28,578 INFO sqlalchemy.engine.base.Engine ()
Out[11]: 
    ...
```

...unless another loading strategy is used explicitly:

```
In [16]: session.query(GroupMembership).options(lazyload('person')).all()
2018-04-05 21:10:52,404 INFO sqlalchemy.engine.base.Engine BEGIN (implicit)
2018-04-05 21:10:52,405 INFO sqlalchemy.engine.base.Engine SELECT group_memberships.id AS group_memberships_id, group_memberships.person_id AS group_memberships_person_id, group_memberships.group_id AS group_memberships_group_id 
FROM group_memberships
2018-04-05 21:10:52,405 INFO sqlalchemy.engine.base.Engine ()
```

If you need alternate orderings from time to time, you'll have to revert to issuing a full query that uses [explicit eager loading](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/orm/tutorial.html#explicit-join-eagerload) and order by:

```
In [42]: g = session.query(Group).\
    ...:     filter_by(id=1).\
    ...:     join(GroupMembership).\
    ...:     join(Person).\
    ...:     options(contains_eager('group_memberships')
    ...:             .contains_eager('person')).\
    ...:     order_by(Person.last_name.desc()).\
    ...:     one()
    ...:             

In [43]: [m.last_name for m in g.members]
Out[43]: ['30', '29', '28', '27', '26', '25', '24', '23', '22', '21']
```