# How to sort by hybrid property on a one-on-one relationship in SQLAlchemy with a reference on the same table twice?

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

I have a table called `User` and `Document`. 
The table `User` holds:

```
first_name
…
```

`Document` holds:

```
id
created_by_id
deleted_by_id
…
```

I want to sort the Document table by the `first_name`. Therefore, I created the relationships `creation_user` and `deletion_user`. Both foreign keys `created_by_id` and `deleted_by_id` reference the same table. The hybrid property `created_by` shall be sorted on:

```py
creation_user = relationship("User", foreign_keys=[created_by_id], lazy="joined")
deletion_user = relationship("User", foreign_keys=[deleted_by_id], lazy="joined")

@hybrid_property
def created_by(self):
    if self.creation_user:
        return self.creation_user.first_name
    else:
        return None

@created_by.expression
    def created_by(cls):
        return User.first_name
```

Unfortunately, SQLAlchemy does not match the correct user and the resulting SQL query looks like this:

```sql
SELECT … 
FROM   document 
       LEFT OUTER JOIN [user] AS user_1 
                    ON user_1.id = document.created_by_id 
       LEFT OUTER JOIN [user] AS user_2 
                    ON user_2.id = document.deleted_by_id 
WHERE  document.id = ? 
ORDER  BY [user].first_name ASC
```

Is there a way to use the hybrid property or a hybrid expression (see [sqlalchemy docs](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/13/orm/extensions/hybrid.html#working-with-relationships)) so that the ORDER BY statement resolves to `ORDER BY user_2.first_name ASC`?

Answer (score 1):

A solution that is "semi SQLAlchemy" is to use `text` as following:

```
def sort_docs(ids, order)
   if order.lower() not in ['asc', 'desc']:
      return None
   statement = """
   SELECT documents.id AS documents_id, documents.created_by_id AS 
    documents_created_by_id, documents.deleted_by_id AS documents_deleted_by_id, 
    users_1.id AS users_1_id, users_1.first_name AS users_1_first_name, users_2.id AS 
    users_2_id, users_2.first_name AS users_2_first_name 
   FROM documents 
   LEFT OUTER JOIN users AS users_1 ON users_1.id = documents.created_by_id 
   LEFT OUTER JOIN users AS users_2 ON users_2.id = documents.deleted_by_id
   WHERE documents_id in :ids
   ORDER BY users_1.first_name {}
   """.format(order)
   sql_statement = text(statement)
   result = db.session.query(Document).from_statement(sql_statement.bindparams(ids=ids))
   return result
```

This way you will retrieve your required documents as an object of `Document` model sorted by the user's first name in the requested order.

Answer (score 0):

Having the hybrid expression specify the required user name generates the desired ordering

```
@created_by.expression
def created_by(cls):
    return sql.select([User.first_name]).where(User.id == cls.created_by_id)
```

Although the generated query adds an additional subquery rather than referencing the aliased table:

```sql
SELECT documents.id AS documents_id, documents.created_by_id AS documents_created_by_id, documents.deleted_by_id AS documents_deleted_by_id, users_1.id AS users_1_id, users_1.first_name AS users_1_first_name, users_2.id AS users_2_id, users_2.first_name AS users_2_first_name 
FROM documents 
LEFT OUTER JOIN users AS users_1 ON users_1.id = documents.created_by_id 
LEFT OUTER JOIN users AS users_2 ON users_2.id = documents.deleted_by_id 
ORDER BY (SELECT users.first_name 
          FROM users 
          WHERE users.id = documents.created_by_id)
```

Another approach would be to define the ordering on the relationship:

```
creation_user = relationship("User", foreign_keys=[created_by_id], lazy="joined", order_by="User.first_name")
```

This produced the SQL specified in the question, and removes the need for the hybrid attributes:

```sql
SELECT documents.id AS documents_id, documents.created_by_id AS documents_created_by_id, documents.deleted_by_id AS documents_deleted_by_id, users_1.id AS users_1_id, users_1.first_name AS users_1_first_name, users_2.id AS users_2_id, users_2.first_name AS users_2_first_name 
FROM documents 
LEFT OUTER JOIN users AS users_1 ON users_1.id = documents.created_by_id 
LEFT OUTER JOIN users AS users_2 ON users_2.id = documents.deleted_by_id 
ORDER BY users_1.first_name
```

However if you ever want a different order, you'll need to override the loading strategy - see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44817668/5320906).

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer! How do I write the hybrid expression if I want to add DESC at the end of the SQL statement?